# MVC: View displaying a grouped list

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view

I am using MVC 5 on Asp.net Framework and would like to create a view that groups information like below:

```
Animal Species: Lion
      Individual: Mufusa, age 6
      Individual: Simba, age 2
Animal Species: Wolf
      Individual: Lupa, age 5
      Individual: Charlie, age 3
```

Right now I'm using a "@foreach (var item in Model)" statement in my View file and the output looks like:

```
Animal Species: Lion
     Individual: Mufusa, age 6
Animal Species: Lion
     Individual: Simba, age 2
Animal Species: Wolf
     Individual: Lupa, age 5
Animal Species: Wolf
     Individual: Charlie, age 3
```

Any suggestion on how to do this?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to share the relevant code of view and the model class

Comment: @HSpeckman could you post the Linq for it

Answer (score 0):

```
     var queryGroupBySpecies = from animal in animals
                                   group new { animal .FirstName, animal.age}  75 into animalGroup 
select animalGroup ;
```

And then you will Iterate foreach Twice

```
   foreach (var animalGroup in queryGroupBySpecies )
    { 
        foreach (var animal in animalGroup )
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{animal.FirstName} {animal.age}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@model List<Igrouping<string, Animals>>
<h1>List of Animals</h1>
<ul> 
  @foreach( var animalGroup in Model){
    <li>Animal Species: @animalGroup.Key</br>
      <ul>
         @foreach(var animal in animalGroup){
           <li>Individual: @animal.Name age <span style="color:red">@animal.age</span>
           </li>
          }
      </ul>
     </li>
   }
 </ul>
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation about *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context, and makes your answer more useful for future readers.